# What are the special things about <a> tag

Tags: html, anchor

**Anchor tag** is one of the very important element in HTML that is used for connectivity in web pages. There are many special things about this tag. One of the important things I came to know about today is the **"rel"** attribute in **<a>** tag, that is used to avoid search-engines to index a link.

Can you guys please share any other interesting information about this  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of goodies here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element

Interesting also is the `type` attribute.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-hyperlink-type

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: [This link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html) is a more comprehensive and accurate resource :P

Comment: There are some really misleading half-truths in that. As usual — **don't go near W3Schools**.